# How to propage errors from nested Eithers in Arrow-kt?

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, arrow-kt

I have some code that looks like this:

```
data class MyStrings(val a: String, val b: String)

sealed class Error {
    object SpecificError0 : Error()
    object SpecificError1 : Error()
    object SpecificError2 : Error()
}

fun either2(): Either<Error, String> =
Either.catch { throw RuntimeException("Either 2") }.mapLeft { Error.SpecificError2 }

fun either4(): Either<Error, MyStrings> =
Either.catch {

    MyStrings(
        a = "Hello",
        b = either2().getOrElse { "" }
    )

}.mapLeft { Error.SpecificError2 }
```

This will swallow the error from either2().

I'm trying to find a way to throw this error from either2 back if possible.

I know I can do something like this:

```
fun either5(): Either<Error, MyStrings> =
either2()
    .flatMap {
        Either.Right(
            MyStrings(
                a = "Hello",
                b = it
            )
        )
    }
```

but it seems strange to call something *before* I need it!

Any thoughts on how I can change either4()? Sorry if this is a n00b question, but I'm still trying to wrap my head around functional programming and Arrow.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kumbera,

In the last snippet you're not really calling it *before* you need it, but semantically it does look that way. Since `MyStrings` depends on the result of `either2()`, but we can rewrite it in a nicer way that scales much nicer without nesting callbacks.

You can improve these snippets by utilising Arrow's computation blocks, which allow extracting values out of `Either` in a safe way.

```kotlin
fun either5(): Either<Error, MyStrings> = either.eager {
  MyStrings(a = "Hello", b = either2().bind())
}
```

What happens here is that when you call `bind` it will either return the value of `Either.Right`, or it will immediately return the `Either.Left` returned by `either2()` as the result of `either.eager`.

There is also a `suspend` variant of the `either` computation block that you can use directly as

```kotlin
suspend fun either6(): Either<Error, MyString> = either {
  delay(100)
  MyStrings(a = "Hello", b = either2().bind())
}
```

I hope that completely answers your question!

Comment: This is beautiful! Thank you. I assume the eager computational blocks also support multiple either binds?

I currrently have mulitple flatmaps like this:

    either0()
        .flatMap {
            either1()
        }
        .flatMap{
            either2()
        }

and so on

I assume these either1() and either2() calls can be made within the same eager block?

Thank you so much for your answer, and your your contribution to Arrow. Its a beautiful library.

Comment: Yes, it supports an infinite amount of `bind`s inside of `either { }`. You're very welcome & thank you for the kind compliment.!